# Query to get number of rows based on condition

Tags: android, sqlite, count, cursor

In my application,I need to get the total number of rows count that has particular value in "status"column.This is the code I tried,

```
String unreadquery="(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM TABLE_MESSAGES WHERE KEY_STATUS="0")";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(unreadquery, null);

int a=cursor.getCount();
```

But it was showing error in query statement.How can I get the number of rows count that has 0 value in particular column?

Thanks!

This is code to create table:

```
public static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "Messages";

String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FROM + " TEXT," + KEY_TO + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BODY + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
```

Comment: What is the type of KEY_STATUS? Are TABLE_MESSAGES and KEY_STATUS actual names or the constants? And what exactly is the error?

Comment: yeah....KEY_STATUS is the column variable and is the type o "TEXT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `KEY_STATUS` is a text column, use single quote. Also, from your comments, `TABLE_MESSAGES` and `KEY_STATUS` are constants that define table and column names.

```
String unreadquery="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " 
    + TABLE_MESSAGES + " WHERE " + KEY_STATUS + "='0'";
```

Comment: Can you show how you declare TABLE_MESSAGES? I suspect this is not a table name but a constant you defined in the code for your table name.

Answer (score 1):

You use parentheses around queries only for subqueries.

Furthermore, `TABLE_MESSAGES` and `KEY_STATUS` are Java symbols, so you have to place their *values* into the SQL string:

```java
String unreadquery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TABLE_MESSAGES+
                     " WHERE "+KEY_STATUS+" = '0'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write simplly

```
int a=0;   
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
String unreadquery="SELECT * FROM TABLE_MESSAGES WHERE KEY_STATUS="0 ";
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(unreadquery, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
if(cursor.getCount()>0)
{
    a=cursor.getCount();
}
cursor.close();
db.close();
return a;
```

Comment: can you please post the error you are getting on query statement

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what you did, just get rid of "COUNT" in the query and just in case create beforehand the argument for rawQuery() like this:

```
String [] keyStatusValue = {"0"};
String unreadquery="(SELECT * FROM TABLE_MESSAGES WHERE KEY_STATUS =?");
// Notice I didn't add COUNT
// and created a String array no matter if keystatus was set as Integer

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(unreadquery, keyStatusValue);

int a=cursor.getCount();
```

That's my advice as it worked fine this way for me.